# insert node inbetween two others in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

so I want to add inbetween two nodes of a linked list a new node whose data field basically contains the sum of the the previous and the next node. I can't understand why once I enter the while loop I can't get out of it. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
void modify_list (node *head) {
nodo *it = head;
nodo *prev = NULL;
int n_prev = 0;
int n_next = 0;
int sum = 0;
it = it->next;
prev = it;
while (it->next != NULL) {
    it->data = n_next;
    prev->data = n_prev;
    sum = n_next + n_prev;
    node *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new == NULL) {
        printf("Error.\n");
        return;
    }
    memset(nuovo, 0, sizeof(node));
    new->data = sum;
    prev->next = new;
    new->next = it;
    sum = 0;
    prev = it;
    it = it->next;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

When you start the iteration, you are using:

```
it = it->next;
prev = it;
```

`it` and `prev` are pointing to the same node. A little while later, you are using:

```
prev->next = new;
```

which is the same as:

```
it->next = new;
```

That means `it->next` points to the new node. That means, you never really go past the newly created nodes.

You can fix this by using:

```
prev = it;
it = it->next;
```

before the start of the `while` loop.

I would make that more robust by using:

```
prev = it;
if ( it != NULL )
{
   it = it->next;
}
```

At this time, `it` could be NULL. Change the conditional in the `while` statement to:

```
while (it != NULL) {
```

Comment: I did what you suggested and the loop bug is solved, but it still crashes. If there are 5 nodes in my list it loops 4 times (which should be fine), but right after the last loop everything freezes.

Comment: Do you know which line it crashes at?

Answer (score 0):

May I first suggest breaking your code up in smaller parts
Have a function that inserts a new object
For a singly linked list, this should insert after:

```
void InsertAfter( Node* n, DATA data )
{
    Node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = n->next;
    n->next = newnode;
}
```

Then you have a function to find the insert-point
It could be for example

```
Node* FindLastSmaller( Node* n, DATA data )
{
    while(true)
    {
        if( ! n->next ) return n;
        if( n->next->data > data ) return n;
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

Then they become easy to combine:

```
void InsertSorted( Node* n, DATA data )
{
    Node* inspos = FindLastSmaller(n,data);
    InsertAfter(inspos,data);
}
```

You can avoid adding special-cases for empty list, if `head` always 
exists, and contains no data. (its a dummy node)